# clickhouse Columns are from different tables

Tags: sql, database, clickhouse

i want to calculate the contain relationship ,Columns a.fistname and b.fullname are from different tables a and b,for example：

```
CREATE TABLE users (uid Int16, firstname String) ENGINE=Memory;
INSERT INTO users VALUES (1231, 'john');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (6666, 'ksenia');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (8888, 'alice');

CREATE TABLE users_money (fullname String, money Int16) ENGINE=Memory;
INSERT INTO users_money VALUES ('johnblack', 33);
INSERT INTO users_money VALUES ('jonhwhite', 48);
INSERT INTO users_money VALUES ('aliceblack', 50);

SELECT a.firstname,b.fullname,b.money FROM users a LEFT JOIN   users_money  b on startswith(b.fullname,a.firstname)==1;
```

i hope this startswith can work,but i got error
" Unsupported JOIN ON conditions. Unexpected 'startswith(fullname, firstname)': While processing startswith(fullname, firstname). (INVALID_JOIN_ON_EXPRESSION)"

you can try:  https://fiddle.clickhouse.com/

the result i want:

```
john    johnblack   33
john    Jonhwhite   48
ksenia      0
alice   aliceblack  50
```

Comment: select * from (
SELECT * from users a LEFT JOIN   users_money  b on 1==1)
where startsWith(fullname,firstname);

Answer (score 1):

JOIN conditions require an equality operator:

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/join/#on-section-conditions

For example you can split the full name and reuse the first element in the JOIN condition

```
CREATE TABLE users (uid Int16, firstname String) ENGINE=Memory;
INSERT INTO users VALUES (1231, 'John');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (6666, 'Ksenia');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (8888, 'Alice');

CREATE TABLE users_money (uid Int16,fullname String, money Int16) ENGINE=Memory;
INSERT INTO users_money VALUES (1231,'John Black', 33);
INSERT INTO users_money VALUES (1231,'Jonh  White', 48);
INSERT INTO users_money VALUES (8888,'Alice  Black', 50);

SELECT a.firstname, splitByWhitespace(b.fullname)[1] as splitFN,b.money FROM users a LEFT JOIN   users_money  b on a.firstname == splitFN
```

Output:

```
John    John    33
Ksenia      0
Alice   Alice   50
```

Comment: i modify my example，please help @Ryadh Dahimene